# Finding address from function name

Tags: windows, immunity-debugger, functions, address

By checking the human-readable strings in my target application, I found several interesting function names:

```
...
DataIntegrityError
GetObjectIdsOfDuplicateLinksErrors
GetInvalidClusterIdsExists
Main
IsCommandLineInvalid
ShowDebugOnlyOptions
DoDecrypt
IStorageLogger
DoExport
DoImport
IsDebugOptionActive
GetRootPath
...
```

Using Immunity Debugger (or any other free debugger, IDA doesn't appear to be compatible with my target application), how can I jump to one of these functions, say `DoDecrypt`?

I can only find commands to jump to an address, so how can I find a function's address from it's name?

Answer (score 8):

### Ollydbg

- if you want to search references for intermodular functions (calls to dll libraries) , go to : searche for -> All intermodular calls.
- if you want to search for all readable labels (including that every human readable function) go to : searche for -> Name in all modules , or current module.

[image]