# Ollydbg: Function name list like in IDA

Tags: ida, windows, ollydbg, debugging, executable

I'm new with reverse engineering and especially with Ollydbg, I have little experience with IDA and currently trying to get used to Olly. My questions are:
 1.Is there any window which would show function list like in IDA? To be more spesific here is what I'm talking [about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZhnS.jpg). How to bring such window in Olly?
2. During investigation if I jump into some function(static analysis) how to get back? I mean is there anything that has same functionality as 
[these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HTQG.jpg) keys do?
Sorry if questions sound silly I'm new with this stuff. thanks :)

Comment: for the 1st question https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9169/finding-address-from-function-name/9170#9170 , for the 2nd use callstack

Answer (score 3):

1 Ctrl +n  or right click view names / view intermodular calls

2  ctrl+ or ctrl - to jump back and forth.

Or open shortcut editor in ollydbg v2 and set your favorite shortcut for navigation